# How can I get the MapView.Marker to display on react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am having some trouble with a piece of react-native-maps code. The map displays fine but I cannot get the markers to display. I tried hardcoding the markers to my initial region. I am not getting any errors. I have also tried zooming out completely and the markers do not show anywhere.

```
this.state = {
        peepsLocations: [
            {
                rotation: 78,
                position:{
                    latitude: 26.12241,
                    longitude: -80.14238,
                }

            }, {
                rotation: 90,
                position:{
                    latitude: 26.12235,
                    longitude: -80.14638,
                }

            }, {
                rotation: 10,
                position: {
                    latitude: 26.12231,
                    longitude: -80.14338,
                }
            },
        ]
    };

    this.initialRegion = {
        latitude: 26.12231,
        longitude: -80.14338,
        latitudeDelta: .00922,
        longitudeDelta: .00421
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this._onRegionChange.call(this, this.initialRegion)
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                provider="google"
                initialRegion={this.initialRegion}
                style={styles.fullScreenMap}/>
            {
                this.state.peepsLocations.map((peepLocation, i) => (
                    <MapView.Marker
                    key={i}
                    coordinate={peepLocation.position}
                    title={`peep ${i}`}
                    description={`peepLocation.rotation.toString() this peep is ...`}
                    >

                    </MapView.Marker>
                ))
            }

        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Instead of looping thru an array, did you tried to just render one of the marker and get it working first? Was it showing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It suddenly clicked while looking at the code with a fresh perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake really that I did not spot initially. I closed the MapView before returning the Markers. It wasn't until I stepped away for a few hours and went back with a new strategy that I saw the problem.

Thanks for your patience and helping a noob.